# In PHP, what is the `ClosedGeneratorException`?

Tags: php, exception

When looking through the output of [`get_declared_classes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) in PHP 7.0 and 7.1, I noticed a **`ClosedGeneratorException`**.

The manual does not make [much mention of it](http://php.net/results.php?q=ClosedGeneratorException&l=en&p=all) and it does not seem to be listed on either the [Predefined Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.exceptions.php) or [SPL exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php) entries in the manual.

Even the source-code does [not hold much information about it](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?q=ClosedGeneratorException).

**So, what is the `ClosedGeneratorException`?**

<sup>(What is it for? When does it occur? When should it be used?)</sup>

Comment: FWIW, it's thrown here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/02d6c259b9ba4a2ad8f54471860ac0c446b69af0/Zend/zend_generators.c#L636

Comment: Found this in google [link](https://airbrake.io/blog/php-exception-handling/closedgeneratorexception) i hope its helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Based on responses in the comments I was able to answer my own question*

---

The [code in the PHP core that throws this exception](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.0/Zend/zend_generators.c#L507) states:

```
    /* php-src/Zend/zend_generators.c */

    zend_throw_exception(
        zend_ce_ClosedGeneratorException,
        "Generator yielded from aborted, no return value available",
        0
    );
```

There is [an article on airbrake.io](https://airbrake.io/blog/php-exception-handling/closedgeneratorexception) that goes into the details of `ClosedGeneratorException`:

> A `ClosedGeneratorException` occurs when attempting to perform a traversal on a generator that has already been closed or terminated.

In other words, when the generator has run out of values, requesting a new value will trigger this exception.<sup>(1)</sup>

Based on [this test from the PHP core](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.0/Zend/tests/generators/mutli_yield_from_with_exception.phpt) I've constructed two scenario's where an `ClosedGeneratorException` is thrown (and caught).

This behaviour can easily be emulated by throwing an exception from within an inner generator (using the [`yield from` syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php#control-structures.yield.from)). The exception is *only* thrown from inside a Generator. (Although it *can* be caught outside the generator).

The two scenario's are attached below. Both example can be seen running on ideone.com<sup>(2)</sup><sup>(3)</sup>

The output of both examples is as follows:

- Catching `ClosedGeneratorException` inside  a Generator<sup>(2)</sup>

  ```
  Generator: 0
  1
  Generator: 1
  Caught ClosedGeneratorException
  ```
- Catching `ClosedGeneratorException` outside a Generator<sup>(3)</sup>

  ```
  Generator: 0
  Caught Generic Exception
  Generator: 1
  Caught ClosedGeneratorException
  ```

### Footnotes

1. The article provides an example to trigger the exception but it looks like the example does not work (as a regular exception is thrown).
2. Catching `ClosedGeneratorException` inside  a Generator: https://ideone.com/FxTLe9
3. Catching `ClosedGeneratorException` outside a Generator: https://ideone.com/ipEgKx

### Code examples

Catch `ClosedGeneratorException` inside a generator:

```
<?php

class CustomException extends Exception {}

function from() {
    yield 1;
    throw new CustomException();
}

function gen($gen) {
    try {
        yield from $gen;
    } catch (\ClosedGeneratorException $e) {
        yield "Caught ClosedGeneratorException";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        yield "Caught Generic Exception";
    }
}

$gen = from();
$gens[] = gen($gen);
$gens[] = gen($gen);

foreach ($gens as $g) {
    $g->current(); // init.
}

foreach ($gens as $i => $g) {
    print "Generator: $i\n";
    print $g->current()."\n";
    $g->next();
}
```

Catch `ClosedGeneratorException` outside a generator:

```
<?php

class CustomException extends Exception {}

function from() {
    yield 1;
    throw new CustomException();
}

function gen($gen) {
    yield from $gen;
}

$gen = from();
$gens[] = gen($gen);
$gens[] = gen($gen);

foreach ($gens as $g) {
    $g->current(); // init.
}

foreach ($gens as $i => $g) {
    print "Generator: $i\n";
    try {
        $g->current();
        $g->next();
    } catch (\ClosedGeneratorException $e) {
        print "Caught ClosedGeneratorException\n";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        print "Caught Generic Exception\n";
    }
}
```